# Sass variable concatenation in loops in Shopify

Tags: sass, shopify

My SCSS compiles fine on sassmeister [1](https://gist.github.com/phlillip/0b5b390bce9f0c74d812394b7f48e089):

```
$black:          "black_rgb(0,0,0)";
$honey-brown:        "honey-brown_rgb(144,122,106)";
$red:                "red_rgb(255,0,0)";

$paints: $black, $honey-brown, $red;

@each $color in $paints {

$colSplit:  str-index($color, _);
$colName:   str-slice($color, 1, $colSplit - 1);
$colVal:    str-slice($color, $colSplit + 1);

.paint-#{$colName}-paint {background-color: #{$colVal};}
}
```

However Shopify is throwing an error:

> Invalid CSS after ".paint-str-slice": expected selector, was
>   "("black_rgb(0,0..." at 9706

So it looks like the variable concatenation `.paint-#{$colName}-paint` isn't working properly.

I am not sure if it is to do with versions of software - I set Sassmeister to the lowest settings (v3.3.14) but it still works fine there. I do not know how to find out the version of scss Shopify uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Shopify uses an old version of Sass which doesn't support some of the latest features such as @import for partials or indeed Maps[1](https://github.com/Shopify/slate/wiki/Styles-with-Liquid#liquid-with-css-custom-properties):

> > Note: Shopify is using a forked version of Sass v3.2 which does not support importing partial Sass files with the @import directive. This may cause some issues when trying to work with 3rd party Sass libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a map:

```
$paints:(
  black:         rgb(0,0,0),
  honey-brown:   rgb(144,122,106),
  red:           rgb(255,0,0)
);

@each $name, $color in $paints {
  .paint-#{$name}-paint {background-color: $color;}
}
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know about maps that is a much cleaner approach and I have learned something, however I am still getting an error: `Invalid CSS after " black": expected ")", was ": rgb(0,0,0)" `

Comment: mmmh... using an hexadecimal without using rgb()? #000000, #ff0000... change something?