# Sass Map and For Loop Not Compiling

Tags: web, sass

I'm having some issues trying to get my Sass @for loop to work with a map of spacer value variables I have set.

Usually the below code will work, not sure if it's my unrested mind or if there is actually something I have done incorrectly.

Here's my Sass map:

```
$spacer:   1rem;

$spacers:(
   0: 0,
   1: ($spacer * .25),
   2: ($spacer * .5),
   3: $spacer,
   4: ($spacer * 1.5),
   5: ($spacer * 3),
   6: ($spacer * 4)
);
```

Here's the for loop I'm trying to get to work:

```
@for $i from 0 through 6 {
   .padd-top-#{$i} {
      padding-top: map-get($spacers, #{$i});
   }
}
```

I have tried turning the compiler off and on again as sometimes this can cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with numbers, don't use interpolation syntax: `#{ }`

```
$spacer:   1rem;

$spacers:(
   0: 0,
   1: $spacer * .25,
   2: $spacer * .5,
   3: $spacer,
   4: $spacer * 1.5,
   5: $spacer * 3,
   6: $spacer * 4
);

@for $i from 0 through 6 {
   .padd-top-#{$i} {
      padding-top: map-get($spacers, $i);
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I thought it'd be something like that. Thanks for your help @ReSedano

Comment: @ReSedano : How can I check which css processor is installed in project scss or sass?

Comment: @HidaytRahman Checking this only from CSS compiled? I really don't know.

Comment: Ok, I am getting the issue in for loop, interpolation in my application it's es6 based. but the same code works fine on ``sassmeister.com``

Comment: @HidaytRahman Have you try to change the sass version you installed in your pc? Another attempt: try to transform the loop using sass (not scss) syntax. Javascript version you use should not be a problem.

Comment: In web.config its showing scss and in other projects like angular it's working fine

Comment: @HidaytRahman Mmmh.. I remember that there are some scss 'limitations' using some framework (Shopify is an example => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996307/sass-variable-concatenation-in-loops-in-shopify/52998330#52998330). Could be something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196317/discussion-between-hidayt-rahman-and-resedano).

Comment: @HidaytRahman Unfortunatly I can't, I'm sorry: I'm at work now and my boss is walking around the desks like a condor... ;-)

Comment: Ohhh. It's fine, actually, I am not using any framework. please have a look into my packages
 ``"css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
        "html-webpack-include-assets-plugin": "^1.0.4",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
        "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
        "postcss": "^7.0.0",
        "postcss-hexrgba": "^1.0.1",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
        "precss": "^3.1.2",
        "style-loader": "^0.21.0"``